# hang when excute GetWindowText() in a dll

Tags: c++, window, hook, msdn

The code :

```
HWND hWnd;  //this is a window handle of current process 
/*
*here is executed in a dll in current process , and it will hang 
*when hWnd is a window which is created by current process.
*/
WCHAR lpwWndName[1000];
GetWindowText(hWnd,lpwWndName,1000);
```

I had read the MSDN :

1,When hWnd is created by another process , GetWindowText will get the title from a special space;

2,When hWnd is created by current process ,GetWindowText will send a WM_GETTEXT to hWnd,this method may hang if the hWnd doesn't response WM_GETTEXT.

How to resove this issue ? Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this issue is excute GetWindowText() in the message process function.

```
message process function()
switch(code)
{
case WM_COMMAND:
  GetWindowText(hWnd);
  break;
case WM_GETTEXT:
  break;
}
```

if hWnd is created by current process , GetWindowText() will send a WM_GETTEXT to the window , and wait for the result,but the WM_GETTEXT will be processed after process WM_COMMAND.And then it deadlocks.